# Proof that a sequence of irrational numbers converges to a rational number.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> ***Let $x_0 \in Q$ where $Q$ is the set of rational numbers. Show that there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ of irrational numbers such that $x_n \to x_0$.***

Is the following proof correct?

Let $x_n = x_0\cdot2^{1/2n}$.

$x_n$ is irrational $\forall n$. By product of limits $x_n \to x_0$. QED.

Comment: The proof is correct. Note, however, that you are relying on the facts that $2^{1/2n} \rightarrow 1$ and $2^{1/2n}$ is irrational for each $n$. If this is a homework problem, you should make sure you're allowed to make these claims without proof.

Comment: Yes, it works. Another example is $x_n = x_0 + \sqrt{2}/n$.

Comment: This fails when $x_0=0$ since then $x_n$ is rational too. I prefer Bungo's argument.